# Comment traduire «...an elusive earthiness » (vin) ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

> Graceful yet seductive, this Pinot Noir is laced with polished notes
> of cherries and red berries swimming amongst supple tannins and **an
> elusive earthiness**.

L'adjectif [*elusive*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elusive), c'est ce qui est difficile à saisir, ce qui échappe à quelque chose, et le [*earthiness*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/earthiness), c'est la substantivation de l'[adjectif](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/earthy) référant à la terre, dans le contexte d'un vin.

Comment traduit-on *an elusive earthiness* dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 1):

« Earthiness » est défini comme « the state of being earthy » ; « earthy » a [deux](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/earthy#Adjective) définitions qui sont possibles.

> 1/ Resembling dirt or soil (i.e. earth).
> ♦ The earthy smell of fresh turned loam told me the farmer had started plowing this morning, the definitive sign of spring for me.
> 2/ Down-to-earth, not artificial, natural.
> ♦ She was an earthy soul, the salt of the earth as they say of such rural folk, untarnished by false civilization.

Les appréciations de connaisseur extraites de cet article, *[At the Crossroads of Viticulture, Oenology and Anthropology](https://www.theexaminernews.com/at-the-crossroads-of-viticulture-oenology-and-anthropology/)*, qui justement nous informent sur les Pinots noirs en termes de « earthiness », sont une assurance qu'il n'est pas  question du sens « 2/ ».

> To match the earthiness of the local beef and vegetables, what was desired was a balanced wine with similar earthy characteristics that would add to, not detract from, the richness of the stew. The local winemakers chose a grape and a style that complemented and enhanced their local cuisine.
>
> Hence, the Pinot Noir grape was singled out and the Burgundian style of Pinot Noir wine was born.

On ne peut donc pas parler d'un gout terre à terre ou naturel puisque le mets qu'il accompagne le mieux, le bœuf bourguignon a une qualité similaire ; c'est donc qu'il s'agit d'une qualité particulière de la terre même d'où les produits proviennent. Le sens serait donc « 1/ », cela mis à part qu'une spécialisation au domaine des produits alimentaires est nécessaire : « gout de terre » ne peut pas être ce dont il s'agit, bien que — on le voit par la suite — il y a une possibilité de traduction qui ne diffère pas tellement du simple terme « gout de terre ». Tout ceci ne cherche qu'à expliquer que ce gout dont il est question n'est qu'une sublimation du gout réel de la terre, celui que l'on aurait en en diluant un peu dans de l'eau et en buvant cette solution, et qui serait atroce.

La référence suivante fournit des possibilités reconnues : [earthy wine
français translation: vin de terroir](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english-to-french/wine-oenology-viticulture/3432791-earthy-wine.html).

- (gout) de terroir, terrien, minéral, (*et même*) terreux

On peut trouver pour le terme « minéral » une bonne explication de la notion de « gout de terre » dans cet [article](https://www.vinotrip.com/fr/blog/vin-mineral/), et pour le terme « terreux », dans [celui-ci](https://www.cavesa.ch/definition/terreux.html) (souvent négatif) et dans cet [autre](https://www.pourlesnuls.fr/articles/article/degustation-de-vin-comment-decrire-le-gout-et-les-saveurs) (saveur assez plaisante).

Ces termes adjectivaux sont probablement utilisés pour caractériser le vin directement.

- vin de terroir, vin terrien, vin minéral, vin terreux

[vin de terroir](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=vin+de+terroir)
[vin terrien](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=vin+terrien)
[vin minéral](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=vin+min%C3%A9ral) Dans certains vins- notamment les vins blancs – des notes de craies, de silex, de pierre à fusil,
[vin terreux](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=vin+terreux) arômes de champignons, de sous-bois, de terre du jardin fraîchement bêchée, de feuilles séchées, etc.

De plus, on voit d'après cet [article](https://www.winemag.com/2020/07/23/earthy-wine-term-definition/), que, spécialement dans le cas des Pinots, gout et arôme sont associés sous la dénomination  « earthiness/earthy » ; ils sont justement mentionnés dans ce texte comme étant les plus typiques parmi les vin  sujets à ce phénomène.

> Forest floor. Wet leaves. Rocks slick with rain. When a wine pro uses such descriptors, it’s an attempt to give greater detail to the broader adjective “earthy.” A useful term, earthy encompasses many different aroma and taste experiences. It’s distinct from the other primary aroma categories like herbal, fruit, floral and spice.
> […]
> Earthiness is often accompanied by a savory character, which is the opposite of sweet. This is best demonstrated by the taste of a Pinot Noir from Burgundy, compared to the riper Pinot Noirs from California.

[wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/earthiness-wine.3268113/) montre qu'il ne peut pas exister beaucoup d'autres termes.

Quelques possibilités

- et des évanescences d'arôme et de gout de terroir
- et un arôme et un gout de terroir insaisissables
- et un arôme et un gout terrien fugitifs

Comment: Merci ! Mais je pense qu'un vin exprime le goût de son terroir bien ou mal, que ce dernier varie d'un terroir à l'autre et je ne suis pas certain que terroir reflète quelque chose d'uniforme. Lors d'une modif. on pourrait faire sauter le premier para. et sa référence dans le deuxième. La démonstration qu'il ne s'agit pas de _down to earth_ est inutile, c'est une évidence. In any case earthiness is never about the state of being down to earth anyways.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse   Il ne faut pas oublier « natural » dans la définition ; je sais que c'est assez élémentaire mais on trouve des quantités de références au « natural wine », comme [celle-ci](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6fdrDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22natural+wine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ14253N_uAhXFxoUKHQoSDukQ6AEwCXoECGMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22natural%20wine%22&f=false), par exemple, et  les lecteurs de ces réponses n'ont certainement pas tous votre compréhension avancée de la question.  (1/2)

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse  Il n'y a pas de bien grande démonstration : la viande bovine locale et les primeurs sont toujours des produits naturels et donc la « earthiness to match » n'a rien à voir avec seulement  l'idée de ce qui est naturel. (2/2)

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Il me semble que vous oubliez ce à quoi est voué le FSE : produire une base de données qui pourront être utiles à quiconque fera une recherche. Toute personne qui posera cette question (comment traduire « earthiness » ?) dans le futur, devra être dirigé sur votre question en premier lieu ; on ne peut pas diverger de ces notions  fondamentales. Je vous suggère de faire une copie, si vous trouvez quand même quelque chose d'utile, et de la modifier à votre guise ; d'ailleurs, bien que ce soit une réponse longue, je suis sûr que l'on doit pouvoir ajouter des choses intéressantes.

Comment: ...une recherche de questions précises menant à des réponses précises. Le but n'est pas de ratisser le plus large possible pour attirer le trafic, tel du SEO. Mon but n'est pas d'imposer mon opinion. Ce que je pense c'est que tes réponses ont plus de chances d'être lues si elles vont droit au but.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Ce n'est pas grave ; il y a de toute façon des articles intéressants à lire, dont je fournis les références, et le lecteur vraiment à la recherche d'information fera certainement comme moi et les lira et relira, et ce maigre bout de texte personnel que j'écrit peut-être en trop n'est que dérisoire en comparaison (on n'en fait qu'une bouchée).

Comment: Ce n'est pas le temps pris à lire un para. c'est plutôt l'effet _wall of text_, qui fait qu'une personne ne lit pas du tout.